# WMIService file results sometimes give "object does not support this property"

Tags: vbscript, wmi-query

I am trying to modify all shortcuts on a computer. The script works fine but every now and then throws an error that the .Target property of an object is not available. Since my query only looks up files with a .lnk extension, this should never be the case. (For more details on this error you can see MS docs here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx#H25)

The script in question:

```
strComputer = "."

Set wshShell    = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile WHERE Extension = 'lnk' AND Drive = 'C:'")

For Each objFile in colFiles

    If InStr(1, ucase(objFile.Target), "METER.EXE") Then
        Set objShortcut = wshShell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Name)
                Wscript.Echo "FIXING: " & objShortcut.TargetPath
        End If
Next
```

For the curious: The purpose of this script is to fix dozens of shortcuts on our lab machines which were previously modified to support a "home-grown" licensing/metering application. In all cases the original .EXE path was stripped from the target but can still be found from the shortcut's icon path.

Thanks

EDIT: The complete error message. It seems to appear more often after a restart, but not once I have run the script 2-3 times.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method: 'objFile.Target'

Answer (score 0):

[`CIM_DataFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236.aspx) doesn't have the `Target` property.

I believe you meant to use [`Win32_ShortcutFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.